# How to pass parameter for validation / treatment in RUBY view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a great doubt, I accept tips if they see a better option to do what I want. I have a layout that links to two items the same view >>

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
  <li>
   <%= link_to backoffice_pedidos_path do %>
     Abertos
   <% end %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to backoffice_pedidos_path do %>
      Finalizados
    <% end %>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I want to treat in the view the contents of my select, if it clicks "Abertos", it loads the index with a partial _abertos and if it clicks "Finalizados" it loads the index but with another partial _finalizados. Is there any way to pass some parameter in the link_to so that in the view I can handle it to send to the correct partial? Or any tips on how to stay?

index>>

```
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pedido</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Data/Hora </th>
                        <th>Produtos </th>                    
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                  <% if ??
                  <%= render partial: "backoffice/pedidos/abertos" %>
                  else ??
                  <%= render partial: "backoffice/pedidos/finalizados" %>
                  <% end %>
                </tbody>
```

**partial abertos>>**

```
           <% @pedidos_aguardando.each do |pedido| %>
        <tr> 
          <td><%=pedido.id%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.status%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.created_at%></td>
          <!--<th><%=pedido.produtos.first.produto %></th>-->
          <td><%=pedido.produtos.pluck (:produto)%></td>
          <td width="50px">
              <%= link_to edit_backoffice_pedido_path(pedido), class:"btn btn-primary btn-circle" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

**Partials fechados**

```
           <% @pedidos_finalizados.each do |pedido| %>
        <tr> 
          <td><%=pedido.id%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.status%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.created_at%></td>
          <!--<th><%=pedido.produtos.first.produto %></th>-->
          <td><%=pedido.produtos.pluck (:produto)%></td>
          <td width="50px">
              <%= link_to edit_backoffice_pedido_path(pedido), class:"btn btn-primary btn-circle" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def index
@pedidos_aguardando = Pedido.waiting
@pedidos_finalizados = Pedido.ok
 end
```

**Model**

```
class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :produtos

scope :waiting, -> { where(status: 1) }
scope :ok, -> { where(status: 2) }
end
```

I accept tips and thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a custom parameter to the `link_to` and using that param in the index view to load the partials accordingly

```
<%= link_to backoffice_pedidos_path(flag: "abertos") do %>
  Abertos
<% end %>
<%= link_to backoffice_pedidos_path(flag: "finalizados") do %>
  Finalizados
<% end %>
```

And in the index view, load the partials using the `params[:flag]` like so

```
<% if params[:flag] == "abertos" %>
  <%= render partial: "backoffice/pedidos/abertos" %>
<% elsif params[:flag] == "finalizados" %>
  <%= render partial: "backoffice/pedidos/finalizados" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything else on my controller? Because that just did not work =( It did not render the partial, the condition did not work =( Tks

Comment: Another question, would this use be the best way to follow the best practices in RoR? Or is there another "right" way to do it?